# Set Javascript Key Name from Dynamic Prop in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've created my own `SelectMenu` Vue component that wraps the `vue-select` package select menu component so that I can get a more streamlined ui flow.

My reusable component looks like so:

```js
<v-select 
  :appendToBody="append"  
  filterable 
  :multiple="multiple"
  :label="label" 
  :placeholder="placeholder" 
  :options="options" 
  :autocomplete="autocomplete" 
  :reduce="option => option.id" 
  @input="selected" 
  v-model="model" />
```

This works perfectly except when the options key needs to be something other than `id`

`append` `multiple` `label` `placeholder` `options` are all passed into the component as props and I'd like to pass in the `option` key to use as well.

```js
:reduce="option => option.{passed in key}"
```

I set a prop called `reducer` for lack of a better name:

```js
reducer: {
  type: String,
  default: 'id'
}
```

I tried concatenating it:

```js
:reduce="option => `option.${reducer}`"
```

But of course this produces a string of "option.id" or whatever the reducer prop is.

How can I set this so it'll be interpreted as javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try using bracket notation to get an object's value by a variable key ? [https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-get-object-value-by-variable-key#:~:text=Use%20bracket%20notation%20to%20get,get%20the%20corresponding%20value%20back.&text=Copied](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-get-object-value-by-variable-key#:%7E:text=Use%20bracket%20notation%20to%20get,get%20the%20corresponding%20value%20back.&text=Copied)!

```
:reduce="option => option[reducer]"
```

Comment: Brilliant .. works a charm. I didn't know you could use an object this way. Much appreciated.